# jsRender how to pass child index to parent

Tags: jsrender

I have a header that needs to show (1 of X) on a page.

I can get 'X' from the array length.

so I have a loop:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal__content modal-outerContent">
                        <div class="modal-title">
                            <h3 class="giftMessage__title">
                                add a gift message
                                {{if GiftMessages ~Count > 1 }}
                                <span class="giftMessage__highlight">
                                    ({{:#getIndex() + 1}} of {{:GiftMessages.length}})
                                </span>
                                {{/if}}
                                <button type="button" class=" modal__close" title="Close modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    <span class="icon icon-close"></span>
                                    <span class="hide">Close Modal</span>
                                </button>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-innerContent">

                            {{for GiftMessages ~Count=GiftMessages.length}}
                            <div class="js-basket-message-form hide form" data-step="{{:#index + 1}}">
                                {{include tmpl="#giftMessageTemplate" /}}
                            </div>
                            {{/for}}
```

So as I cycle my for loop how do I pass the current child index value back to the parent. Such that the line with data-step = "{{:#index + 1 }}" gets returned to the parent where I currently have {{:getIndex() + 1}}

My data set :

```
 item {
   message {
      to
      from
      messageContent
    }
   message {
      to
      from
      messageContent
    }
 }
 item { …..
```

Comment: pls add input dataset

Comment: Or better, show a) example data, b) exactly what you want to be rendered for that data - and/or create a jsfiddle with your attempted solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output an array of arrays can do this:

```
  {{for item itemVar="~item"}}
    {{for ~item itemVar="~inner"}}
    .....
    {{/for}}
  {{/for}}
```

For you dataset:

```
var data = {
    item: [
    [
        {to: "a", from: "b", messageContent: "foo"},
      {to: "b", from: "a", messageContent: "bla"}
    ],
    [
        {to: "a1", from: "b1", messageContent: "foo1"},
      {to: "b1", from: "a1", messageContent: "bla1"},
      {to: "b2", from: "a2", messageContent: "bla2"},
    ]
  ]
};
```

The template looks like this:

```
  {{for item itemVar="~item"}}
    <div>item {{:#index}} </div>
    {{for ~item itemVar="~message"}}
       <div> 
         -- message {{:#index}} 
         <b>from:</b> {{:~message.from}};
         <b>to:</b> {{:~message.to}};
         <b>content:</b> {{:~message.messageContent}};
       </div>
    {{/for}}
  {{/for}}
```

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zqb3ckfe/)

---

**Update**
You cannot use the child cycle index in the parent cycle. It doesn’t work like that. Suppose we solve this problem using c JavaScript, have an parent index `i` and children index `j` declare them at the very beginning to avoid visibility problems.

```
var i,j;
```

Now try:

```js
    
        var i = 0, j = 0;
  for (var i; i < 2; i++) {
   console.log("p:" + i);
   for (var j; j < 3; j++) {
    console.log("ic" + j); // j = current index
   }
   console.log("c:" + j); // j = 3 (last index)
  }
```

How can you see it is useless.

---

**Update 2**

You can push variables into the loop from above

```
{{for ~item itemVar="~message" ~parent_index=#index}}
   <div>
     -- item {{:~parent_index}}
     ...
```

Comment: So from your example what I want to do is get the inner loops index and pass it back to the outer loop